# Как по средним значениям пикселей на изображении найти тёмную линию?

Tags: python, opencv

Имеется несколько изображений, на каждом из них есть тёмная линия. Я пробую находить среднее значение всех пикселей на изображении и после находить всё что темнее. Однако, при изменении освещения диапазон значений этой линии смещается и я захватываю лишнее. Также не стоит предлагать cv2.HoughLines, так как на изображении могут присутствовать белый прямые линии. Вот код, который почти идеально подходит для первого изображения, но не подходит для второго и третьего. Как понять, какие необходимо использовать параметры для inRange?

```
import cv2

dst = cv2.imread("test1 (1).png")
dst = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

average_color = tuple([dst[:, :, i].mean() for i in range(dst.shape[-1])])
print(average_color)
thresh = cv2.inRange(dst, (0,0,0), (average_color[0]+15, average_color[1]+15, average_color[2]+5))

cv2.imshow("tresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте дилатацию, затем эрозию. (Ядро подберите лучше круглым минимальным, но таким, чтобы линия пропала). Затем найдите абсолютную разницу между исходной картинкой и тем что получилось.

Comment: Использовал ваш совет, спасибо за идею. Чуть доработал, добавив небольшие коэффициенты к значениям диапазона

Comment: @VladBandarenka поделитесь результатом?

Comment: @Jack_oS, к сожалению, я понял, что поиск линии по цвету не будет хорошо работать для изображения с многими цветами. Поэтому использую HoughLinesP. Код выложил ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Ушёл от идеи поиска линии по цвету, использовал в итоге HoughLinesP. Если у кого будут идеи с цветом, то пишите

```
dst = cv2.imread("name.png")
dst2 = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dst2 = cv2.Canny(dst, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)

lineLength = int(dst.shape[0] * 0.5)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=dst2, rho=1, theta=np.pi / 180,
                         threshold=100, minLineLength=lineLength,
                         lines=np.array([]), maxLineGap=100)

print(lines)
liner = [x[1] for i in lines for x in i]
g = liner.index(min(liner))

for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[g]:
    cv2.line(dst, (0, y1), (dst.shape[0], y2), (50, 180, 60), 7)
```